# I want to draw a line from the center of the bottom from a div to the center of the top from another div?

Tags: html, canvas

Ok I know!

It sounds a little bit weird (probably cause of my english which isnt perfect, but I hope you guys understand me so far) but I want to draw a line (with HTML5) from a div to another div.
But I want to find out the mid of the top from a div or the the mid of the bottom from a div.

Pretty sure I have big thinking barrier ... please help me get over this barrier!

How can I find out?

Thx so far Nubu

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: I draw some lines with the canvas element from html5, but i need the coordinates from the middle of the bottom of this div so i can tell my function where this line can go ... so is there a chance to find out this position?

Answer (score 0):

So, to break it down for you, you first need to determine the coordinates of the div1-bottom-center and div2-top-center. If you use jQuery then this is fairly easy by using [`$(divX).offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), [`$(divX).width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`$(divX).height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/). Then you can use that to draw the line correctly.

An alternative, depending on what you want to accomplish, is to use an existing library for this, such as [jsPlumb](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/jquery/demo.html).

Comment: ok sorry, i didnt write it in my question. i wanna use plain javascript/html5 ... so i just have to figure out where my first div is located in the viewport/screen?